# How to imbricate arrays

Tags: javascript

I need a function like this:

```
function imbricate(...arrays){}
```

Which returns a new array.

```
imbricate(["a","c","d"],["b","c"],["z","a"],["b","y","d"],["e","f","g"])
```

Should returns: z,a,b,y,c,d,e,f,g because:

- a,b,c,d (first pass) `const r1=imbricate(["a","c","d"],["b","c"])`
- z,a,b,c,d (second pass) `const r2=imbricate(r1,["z","a"])`
- z,a,b,y,c,d
- z,a,b,y,c,d,e,f,g

Comment: Can you also share what you have tried?

Comment: `a,b,c,d (first pass)` ?? What's "first pass"? And why would there be a `b`? There is no `b` in the first array... I really don't get your logic

Comment: @JeremyThille I guess the idea is, first 2 arrays have `c`. Since `a` comes before `c`, so does `b`, both `a` and `b` should come before `c`. Now why does `a` come before `b`? Not sure. May be because it came first (*first come, first serve*)

Comment: That doesn't really help me :)

Comment: Shouldn't the result be z,a,b,y,d,c,e,f,g
Because y and d get added after the b in the 4th run, and then e f g added at the end in the 5th?

Comment: please add how the strings are build.

Comment: I am assuming that for each array of elements in the arguments the function should check if the first letter already exists in the previous result. If it does, insert the other characters in the array behind this character in the result. If it doesn't, check if the last element exists in the result, if it does, insert the other characters BEFORE this element. If neither the first and the last are in the result, just add the entire array to the end of the result. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I made this one liner :-) to solve my problem:

```
function imbricate(...arrays) {
function split(refArray, array = []) {
    if (!refArray.some(v => array.indexOf(v) > -1)) return [array];
    let returnArray = [];
    let previousIndex = 0;
    for (const v of refArray) {
        if (array.indexOf(v) > -1) {
            returnArray.push(array.slice(previousIndex, array.indexOf(v) + 1));
            previousIndex = array.indexOf(v);
        }
    }
    if (previousIndex != array.length - 1) returnArray.push(array.slice(previousIndex));
    return returnArray;
}
function merge(refArray = [], array = []) {
    let rangeMinIndex = array.findIndex(v => refArray.indexOf(v) > -1);
    let rangeMaxIndex = array.slice(rangeMinIndex + 1).findIndex(v => refArray.indexOf(v) > -1);
    if (rangeMinIndex == rangeMaxIndex && rangeMinIndex < 0) return [...refArray, ...array];
    if (rangeMaxIndex < 0) rangeMaxIndex = array.length - 1;
    if (rangeMinIndex == rangeMaxIndex && rangeMinIndex == 0) return [...refArray];
    if (rangeMinIndex == rangeMaxIndex)
        return [
            ...refArray.slice(0, refArray.indexOf(array[rangeMinIndex])),
            ...array.slice(0, rangeMaxIndex),
            ...refArray.slice(refArray.indexOf(array[rangeMinIndex]))
        ];

    if (
        array.slice(rangeMinIndex + 1).findIndex(v => refArray.indexOf(v) > -1) == -1 &&
        rangeMaxIndex == array.length - 1
    )
        return [
            ...refArray.slice(0, refArray.indexOf(array[rangeMinIndex]) + 1),
            ...array.slice(rangeMinIndex + 1), //, rangeMaxIndex+1),
            ...refArray.slice(refArray.indexOf(array[rangeMinIndex]) + 1)
        ];
    return [
        ...refArray.slice(0, refArray.indexOf(array[rangeMinIndex]) + 1),
        ...array.slice(rangeMinIndex + 1, rangeMaxIndex + 1),
        ...refArray.slice(refArray.indexOf(array[rangeMinIndex]) + 1)
    ];
}
let current;
for (const array of arrays) {
    if (!current) current = [...array];
    else {
        for (const splitted of split(current, array)) current = merge(current, splitted);
    }
}
return current;
```

}

First array is always the reference, it splits other arrays to chunks containing only bounds based on values included in the reference array, then merge according to the bounds positionning.

Thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following logic:

- Create a dummy array and fill it with values of first array.
- Now loop over remaining arguments and check if current argument is an array or not. If not, following solution ignores it.
- Now create a variable for `previousIndex`(`pIndex` in solution) that will hold position of previously matched index
- If Array, loop over it in descending fashion and check if current element exists or not and save its index in another variable, say `index`

  - If `index` is greater than `-1`, this means value exists in array and we do not have to push it.
  - Now If `pIndex` is `-1` and `index` is `-1`, its a new item and we can push it at the end. Update `pIndex` with new position.
  - If `pIndex` is not `-1`, push current element at this position and shift remaining elements.

```js
function imbricate(){
  var args = arguments;
  var result = [].concat(args[0]);
  for(var i = 1; i< args.length; i++){
    if(!Array.isArray(args[i])) continue;
    var pIndex = -1;
    args[i].reduceRight(function(p,c){
      var index = p.indexOf(c);
      if(index < 0){
        if(pIndex >= 0){
          p.splice(pIndex, 0, c);
          index = pIndex;
        }
        else{
          p.push(c);
          index = p.length - 1;
        }
      }
        
      pIndex = index;
      return p;
    }, result)
  }
  return result;
}

var r = imbricate(["a","c","d"],["b","c"],["z","a"],["b","y","d"],["e","f","g"]);

console.log(r)
```

**Note:** Considering the ambiguity pointed out by @[Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) in comments, this answer can be taken as a reference instead. Above answer considers precedence as *first come, first serve* order. So if you have `[a,c], [b, c], [d, c]`, output would be `[a, b, d, c]`.

Comment: **Note:** If you think, there is anything wrong in the answer, **please** share your feedback as a comment along with your vote.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, except the result should be : z,a,b,y,c,d,e,f,g. 'y' is at the wrong position.

Comment: the `y` position can be disputed, as well as `efg` and why `a` is in front of `b.`

Comment: I agree it depends on the behaviour. I expect a result to be ordered depending on the first reference found (b), so 'y' should be after 'b'.

Comment: 'a' is in front of 'b' because in `const r1=imbricate(["a","c","d"],["b","c"])`  'c' is a reference in both array, so the result is `a,b,c,d`. If no common reference in both array, then push items so `efg` is at the end.

Comment: @Alphapage If we apply same logic for `c` to `y`, then since it is coming in  4th array, `c` has higher preference than `y`. Hence `c, y`

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated my answer with a caveat. If you have any further pointers for me or for readers, please feel free to update answer or add a comment.